# Data structure alignment to implement serialize in C++

Tags: c++, serialization, memory-alignment

I understand the theory of data structure alignment and using this theory to implement serialize. 
However, it hard for me to get start on the real code.
Could someone give me s simple example to show how this work?

Let's say:

```
 Class A {
  private:
     int a;
     char b;
     double c;
     char d;
     char e;
   public:
     void serialize(char * str);
 };
```

How to implement the serialize method to store a aligned data A? Should I just reorder the data structure and padding it? or...

Comment: In-memory data alignment and serialization are two orthogonal aspects. In fact, once data is serialized into a stream of bytes, alignment is no longer a concern.

Comment: @MatthiasVallentin please turn your comment into an answer before someone proposes to use `memcpy` or some similar functions.

Comment: Rather than doing your own serialization, you might check Google Protocol Buffers:  http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/  ... that will handle a lot of the details for you, 'the right way'.

Comment: You don't have to do anything to get data structure alignment. The compiler does it for you. Your question remains unclear.

Answer (score 2):

**Alignment and serialization are two orthogonal aspects.**

The former concerns the in-memory representation of a data structure, whereas the latter relates to its equivalent representation in a sequential form. In other words, once a data structure is serialized into a stream of bytes, alignment is no longer relevant. Similarly, the notion of alignment does not make sense when referring to a stream of serialized bytes.

That said, you should address each issue separately rather than trying to find a joint solution.

Comment: The idea is that we first need to alignment the data structure, in order to get a small sizeof(DATA STRUCTURE). Then, use memcpy() to pass the value to char*. In this way, to send the buffer out.

Comment: If you plan to share the serialized struct in any way (e.g., send it over the network, write it to a file that other machines may read), you will run into trouble with a `memcpy` approach. Alignment then becomes just one among many problems, e.g., you also have to account for byte order. This is not how one should serialize data structures. (@Andre hinted that already in a comment.)